# What is the suggested width and recommended touch size of the iOS 7 A-Z / "rolodex" nav (and what does Apple call it!?)

Tags: gui-design, navigation, lists, ios

I'm wondering: if there were to be a button (such as a "detail disclosure" button [image: Detail disclosure button] ) directly to the left of the A-Z navigation/slider, how much space would  need to be between the two? In other words, what is the recommended touch target of the A-Z slider?

Also: what does Apple call this A-Z slider? It doesn't seem to be addressed in their documentation.

[image: from Apple's iOS7 UI guidelines]

Comment: Regarding your second question, the UITableView can have an Index which can be added by implementing the sectionIndexTitlesForTableView and sectionForSectionIndexTitle methods

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm pretty sure iOS takes care of the spacing for you.  So you need not worry about it, unless you want to mimic this behavior with a custom control.  If that is the case, then Apple recommends minimum touchable area for a button to be [44x44 pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1929010/505093)
2. The A-Z slider is called an *index*, which shows up in an *indexed list*.  See *Figure 1-2* [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW3) Although you could more informally call it an "index bar" or "section index bar"